# Java CompareTO method issues

Tags: java

I am trying to sort out a simple list of students mark with a simple java program however I am getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Student cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

```
public class Student {
public String name;
public int mark;


public Student(String name, int mark){
    this.name=name;
    this.mark=mark;
}


public int compareTo(Student o){
    return this.mark-o.mark;


}
public String toString(){
    String s = "Name: "+name+"\nMark: "+mark+"\n";
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student Class[] = new Student[9];
    Class[0] = new Student("Henry",100);
    Class[1] = new Student("Alex", 10);
    Class[2] = new Student("Danielle",100);
    Class[3] = new Student("Luke",10);
    Class[4] = new Student("Bob",59);
    Class[5] = new Student("Greg",76);
    Class[6] = new Student("Cass",43);
    Class[7] = new Student("Leg",12);
    Class[8] = new Student("Bobe",13);



    Arrays.sort(Class);
    for(int i = 0;i<Class.length;i++){
        System.out.println(Class[i]);
```

Comment: Student class should implement Comparable interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Student` class **must** implement the `Comparable` interface in order to use `Arrays#sort` passing `Student[]` array. The fact that your class currently have a `compareTo` method doesn't mean it implements this interface, you have to declare this:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    //class definition...
}
```

Comment: Of course how silly of me I kept forgetting to put the <Student> at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Make your `Student` class implement `Comparable<Student>`. The `compareTo()` method doesn't work on it's own while sorting.

Also, `Class` doesn't look like a very good variable name. How about using `students`? Also, I see an issue in your `compareTo` method:

```
public int compareTo(Student o){
    return this.mark-o.mark;
}
```

Never compare on the result of subtraction of 2 integers, or longs. The result might overflow. Rather use [`Integer.compare(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) method.
Also, get rid of `public` fields. Make them `private`, and provide `public` getters to access them.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Fawaz1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // تجربه 
        String SS[]=new String[6];
        double GG[]=new double[6];
        SS[0]="fawaz";  
        SS[1]="ahmd";
        SS[2]="hmd";
        SS[3]="fos";
        SS[4]="raid";
        SS[5]="majd";
        
        GG[0]=3.94;
        GG[1]=2.50;
        GG[2]=2.95;
        GG[3]=4.92;
        GG[4]=3.0;
        GG[5]=3.78;
        
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.print(SS[i]+"\t"+GG[i]+"\t");
            if (GG[i]>=4.75)
            {System.out.println("A+");}
            else if(GG[i]>=4.50){
                System.out.println("A");
            } else if(GG[i]>=3.70){
                System.out.println("B+");
            }else if(GG[i]>=3.59){
                System.out.println("B");
            }else if(GG[i]>=2.78){
                System.out.println("C+");
            }else if(GG[i]>=2.55){
                System.out.println("C");
            }else if(GG[i]>=1.52){
                System.out.println("D");
            }else if(GG[i]>=1.10){
                System.out.println("F");
            }
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.